# Need to scale already projected data using d3 geoPath.projection(null)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, html5-canvas

Based on d3 (ver 1.4)  documentation https://github.com/d3/d3-geo/blob/master/README.md#geoProjection , the d3 projection should be set to null to use the data's raw coordinates.   How do I scale if the projection looks correct using null? Here is the code:

```
var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(null)
    .context(context);

bands.features.forEach(function(d, i) {
  context.beginPath();
  context.fillStyle = colors[i];
  context.globalAlpha = .5;
  path(d);
  context.fill();
});
```

I have tried defining my own projection but the projection looks incorrect. Here is the code

```
var project = d3.geoProjection(function(x,y){
    return [x,y]
});

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(project)
    .context(context);
```

Answer (score 2):

I would take a look at d3.geoTransform which should be better suited for showing already projected Cartesian data than d3.projection. From Mike Bostock:

> But what if your geometry is already planar? That is, what if you just want to take projected geometry, but still translate or scale it to fit the viewport?
>
> You can implement a custom geometry transform to gain complete control over the projection process.

To see a better example than what I can do here (and to read the rest of the quote), see [this Bl.ock](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5663666)

For example, for your case you might use something like:

```
    function scale (scaleFactor) {
        return d3.geoTransform({
            point: function(x, y) {
                this.stream.point(x * scaleFactor, y  * scaleFactor);
            }
        });
    }

    path = d3.geoPath().projection(scale(2));
```

---

As for why the custom projection shown

```
var project = d3.geoProjection(function(x,y){
return [x,y] });
```

changes/distorts the projection, I do not know (I had similar results testing this answer), but if this projection's output is useable, it can be scaled fairly easily:

```
var project = d3.geoProjection(function(x,y){
return [x,y] }).scale(1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestion.  My problem turned out to not be a scale problem but a matrix transformation issue.  I am using the d3marchingsquares.isobands software and I needed to transpose my data prior to sending it into marching squares.

My project is create a map similar to https://earth.nullschool.net/ but using Google Maps.

I am adapting Roger Veciana's "Isobands from a geotiff with d3" demo http://bl.ocks.org/rveciana/de0bd586eafd7fcdfe29227ccbdcd511.  This is almost complete but having issues resizing the canvas layer.  Next I am going to overlay Danny Cochran's windable canvas layer over the temperature contours. I updated Danny Cochran's code to work with the latest Google Map's version.