# d3.geoPath() vs d3.geo.path()

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, geojson, topojson

I'm attempting to follow [Mike Bostock's process](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4707858) to project to the bounding box of a feature in a topojson file.  My topojson file is already projected to Texas State Mapping System (EPSG 3081) [from the command line](https://medium.com/@mbostock/command-line-cartography-part-1-897aa8f8ca2c#.bkgvwha6c) using geoproject:

```
d3.geoConicConformal().parallels([34 + 55 / 60, 27 + 25 / 60]).rotate([100, -31 - 10 / 60])
```

However, copying his code exactly and modifying the relevant bits to match my data set results in the error "Uncaught TypeError: path.bounds is not a function" on this line:

```
var b = path.bounds(state),
```

Here is my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JS Mapping Project</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-array.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v2.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #eee;
            }
            svg {
                background-color: #fff;
                border: 1px solid #000;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Width and height
            var w = 1000;
            var h = 850;

            var projection = d3.geoProjection( function(x, y) {
                return [x, y];
            });

            // Create a path generator.
            var path = d3.geo.path()
                .projection();

            //Create SVG element
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            //Load in GeoJSON data
            d3.json("data/topojson/boundary_quantize.json", function(error, json) {
                //Add error handling
                if (error) throw error;

                var states = topojson.feature(json, json.objects.state),
                    state = states.features.filter(function(d) { return d.properties.NAME === "Texas"; })[0];

                projection
                    .scale(1)
                    .translate([0, 0]);

                // Compute the bounds of a feature of interest, then derive scale & translate.
                var b = path.bounds(state),
                    s = .95 / Math.max((b[1][0] - b[0][0]) / w, (b[1][1] - b[0][1]) / h),
                    t = [(w - s * (b[1][0] + b[0][0])) / 2, (h - s * (b[1][1] + b[0][1])) / 2];             

                // Update the projection to use computed scale & translate.
                projection
                    .scale(s)
                    .translate(t);

                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("stroke"," #000")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "2")
                    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(json, json.objects.national)));

                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("stroke"," #000")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "1")
                    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(json, json.objects.state)));

                svg.append("path")
                    .attr("stroke"," #000")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "0.5")
                    .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(json, json.objects.county)));

            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

A few things that I've discovered manipulating the code:

If I remove the projection by changing var path = d3.geo.path().projection(); to var path = d3.geo.path();, the error goes away (because the call to the broken code goes away) but the svg draw is broken:

[image: var path = d3.geo.path();]

If I change the path definition to var path = d3.geoPath();, suddenly the geometry draws correctly:

[image: var path = d3.geoPath();]

This won't work (and I don't know why geoPath() works in the first place) because then the rest of my calls to path fail.

As I was typing this, I realized that I forget the call to my projection variable. I changed .projection(); to .projection(projection);. Now my map looks really weird, but there aren't errors on the path.bounds line as before:

[image: .projection(projection);]

It would seem that my projection definition is wrong, despite using the formula from [this StackExchange answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41230426/523128).

I changed the code from geoProjection() to geoIdentity() based on [Mike Bostock's response to a comment on his Medium article](https://medium.com/@mbostock/yes-use-d3-geoidentity-see-this-example-98843be22363#.bsk83kfbp). My map appeared to be projected, scaled, and centered correctly, but the all black and white color scheme didn't help. I added some quick coloring to the various layers and it now looks very broken:

[image: Correctly projected, scaled, and centered, but broken features.]

I then thought maybe it was because I didn't add the ", function(a,b) { return a !== b; }" to the topojson.mesh function, but doing that made things more broken:

[image: Filtering for a!==b]

I double-checked my topojson file again at mapshaper.org, but my geometry is correct:

[image: Geometry check at mapshaper.org]

At this point I'm stumped. Something is wrong with the way I'm implementing topojson to render my data, but it matches the code I'm seeing in examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had a breakthrough here. By changing the call to the feature from topojson.mesh to topojson.feature, the problem instantly resolved itself.  I don't know why .mesh [works in this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4136647), but it definitely didn't work for me.

[image]

**EDIT:**  I've identified why .mesh has been used in the example. It is to select only the internal boundaries so the coastline is not rendered, which is a great idea from a cartographic perspective. The thing I realized is to not apply a fill to those paths to prevent the drawing errors I had before.